# Como faço para fazer um update ORACLE SQL importando dados de outra tabela?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Meu objetivo é importar os nomes da tabela0 para tabela1, mas sendo validado pelo número do CPF e onde estão faltando os nomes

[image: 1]

```
UPDATE Tabela1
SET nome1 = (SELECT nome0 FROM tabela0)
WHERE CPF1 = (SELECT CPF0 FROM tabela0)
```

está dando erro.. já procurei e não encontrei solução.

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando o comando sql [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F). Que faz exatamente o que deseja. O merge é uma instrução para selecionar linhas de uma ou mais fontes para atualização ou inserção em uma `tabela` ou `view`. Você pode especificar condições para determinar se deve atualizar ou inserir na tabela ou view de destino.

```
MERGE INTO tabela1 t1
USING tabela0 t0
ON (t0.cpf0 = t1.cpf1) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET t1.nome1 = t0.nome0
```

Que é equivalente à:

Quando `t0.cpf0 for igual a t1.cpf1. Desejo que os valores da coluna` t1.nome`sejam atualizados com o valor da coluna`t0.nome0`

O comando seria basicamente este escrito em linguagem natural.

Para mais informações e construções mais elaboradas deste mesmo comando consulte a documentação do comando `merge`.

Answer (score -2):

Faça um [cursor](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-cursor/) , em um [bloco anônimo](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-anonymous-block/).

```
Begin
  For r in (select nome0,CPF1 from tabela0) 
  Loop
    UPDATE Tabela1 SET nome1 = r.nome0
    Where CPF1 = r.CPF1;
  End loop;
End;
```

Existem outras soluções que contornam este problema.

Comment: Aceitando a negativação das repostas , mas vou manter a mesma pois ela pode ser útil (apesar da dúvida ser recorrente).

Comment: não negativei, mas ao tentar executar o código só foi possível ao adicionar um "/" ao final do trecho de código disponibilizado, não sei se é questão de versões do sgbd ou aplicação / ambiente. Usei o sql plus Release 21.0.0.0.0 em um ambiente windows.

Comment: Não você mas alguém o fez , mas a mesma está incompleta.  o barra creio ser coisa do plus.